# Adding to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add one to a variable, but is not working. Why is this?

```
var numElementsDisplay = "5";

$('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(n+' + numElementsDisplay + 1 + ')').attr('style', $(this).attr('style') + '; ' + 'display: none !important');
```

Comment: Why is your variable a string rather than a number?

Comment: $('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(n+' + (numElementsDisplay + 1) + ')').CSS('display','none !important');

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `()` wrap wrap the numeric operation, else a string concatenation will be performed

```
var numElementsDisplay = "5";
$('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(n+' + (+numElementsDisplay + 1) + ')').attr('style', $(this).attr('style') + '; ' + 'display: none !important');
```

---

Also don't know why you want to use `!important`, but if you want to append the `display` rule to the existing set of inlined rules you will have to use a callback, else `this` will not refer to the current element

```
$('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(n+' + (+numElementsDisplay + 1) + ')').attr('style', function () {
    //also will have to use a callback
    return $(this).attr('style') + '; ' + 'display: none !important'
});
```

---

But if you wan tot use `!important` a better solution will be is to use a class like

```
$('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(n+' + (+numElementsDisplay + 1) + ')').addClass('hidden');
```

then

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't appear to be adding the style attribute to the 6th element. Any ideas?

Comment: `numElementsDisplay` is a string, so parentheses don't help.

Comment: @Jrags87 as nnnnnn pointed out, you have created `var numElementsDisplay = "5";` as a string, declare it as a numer to make it work `var numElementsDisplay = 5;` another solution is to use an unary plus to convert the string to a number like `(+numElementsDisplay + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
$('.searchdropdown .element:nth-child(' + (Number(n) + Number(numElementsDisplay) + 1) + ')').attr(...)
```

I don't know what is the var `n` in this context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `n` isn't a Javascript variable, it's part of the css. The literal text `n+` needs to be in the final string.

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the string "5" to numElementsDisplay
change it to

```
var numElementsDisplay = 5;
```

and all will be fine

Comment: This is half of the answer. Would still need to add parentheses.

Comment: true, point taken :)
    (numElementsDisplay + 1)
or even
    parseInt( (numElementsDisplay + 1) )

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear as to whether you want numElementsDisplay to be an integer (ex. 5 + 1 = 6) or a string (numElementsDisplay + 1 =numElementsDisplay1). If you want the first case, then you need to do use:
`parseInt(numElementsDisplay + 1)` . 
Otherwise you should probably have the 1 in quotes, as: `(numElementsDisplay + "1")`.